# Are mocks and stubs implementation details?

Tags: jestjs, tdd, bdd

I have read that with TDD we should approach the entity (function, class etc.) under test from the perspective of the user/caller of the entity. The gist being focusing on the public "interface". This in turn would drive the design and help reason about the design earlier.
But when we need to introduce mocks and stubs into our tests, isn't that an implementation detail?
Why would/should the "user" care about the other entities that are supposed to be there?
E.g.
How to start writing a test for the `PlaceOrder` service which should check with the credit card service if the user has enough money? Putting a mock for the credit card service whilst writing a test from the perspective of the `PlaceOrder` client looks out of place now - because it is an implementation detail; our `PlaceOrder` may call the credit card for each user or it can simply have a cache with scores provided at the creation time.

Comment: "*how to start writing a test for the PlaceOrder service which should check with the credit card service if the user has enough money?*" Remember that you can have different payment processors. PayPal, AmazonPay, other ones. They should expose the same interface, though. So you *don't care* what the user is paying with - if they don't have enough money through PayPal, you'd expect the same behaviour if they didn't have enough money through AmazonPay. At the end of the day, the PlaceOrder should just respond to "not enough money". Shouldn't matter if the message comes from a mock or not.

Comment: I agree, but why should I know about the credit card service at all? That is an architectural/implementation detail. Anyway the answers given are reasonable.

Comment: Because you're testing PlaceOrder. Not the payment processor.

Comment: Yes but providing a mock is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear-cut. As a catch-phrase says: *Tests are specifications.*

When you use [Test Doubles](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) you are, indeed, specifying how your System Under Test (SUT) ought to interact with its dependencies.

I agree that this is *usually* an implementation detail, but there will typically be a few dependencies of a more architectural character.

A common example is an email gateway. If your SUT should send email, that's an observable side effect that the user (or some other stakeholder) cares about.

While you can (and perhaps should?) also run full systems tests that verify that certain conditions produce real emails that land in certain real mailboxes, such test cases are difficult to automate.

Inserting a Test Double that can take the place of an email gateway and verify that the correct message was delivered to the gateway is not only an implementation detail, but an important part of the overall system. In such cases, using a Test Double makes sense.

Yes, Test Doubles specify behaviour, but sometimes, that's exactly what you want.

How much you should rely on this kind of design is an architectural choice. In addition to sending emails, you might choose to explicitly specify that a certain SUT ought to place a message on a durable queue.

You can create entire systems based on asynchronous messaging, which could imply that it'd be architecturally sound to let tests rely on Test Doubles.

In short, I find it a useful heuristic to use Test Doubles for architectural components, and rely mostly on testing [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) for everything else.

For something like an order service, I wouldn't let the order service contact the payment gateway. Rather, I'd implement the order service operations as pure functions, and either pass in a payment token as function arguments, or let the output of functions trigger a payment action.

The book [Domain Modeling Made Functional](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/domain-modeling-made-functional) contains lots of good information about this kind of architecture.

On the other hand, the book [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/goos) contains many good examples of how to use Test Doubles to specify desired behaviour.

Perhaps you'll also find my article [From interaction-based to state-based testing](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/18/from-interaction-based-to-state-based-testing) useful.

In summary: *Tests are specifications.* Test Doubles are specifications. Use them to specify the observable behaviour of the system. Try to avoid using them to specify implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

> But when we need to introduce mocks and stubs into our tests, isn't that an implementation detail?

Yes, in effect.  A bit more precisely, it is additional coupling between your test and the details of your test subject's implementation.

There are two ideas in tension here.  On the one hand, we want that our tests are as representative as possible of how our system will *actually* work; and on the other hand we each of our tests to be an controlled experiment of our implementation, without coupling to shared mutable state.

In some cases, we can disguise some of the coupling by using inert substitutes for our dependency as the *default* case, so that our implementation classes are isolated unless we specifically opt into a shared configuration.

So for PlaceOrder, it might look like using a default CreditCardService that always answers "yes, the customer has enough money".  Of course, that design only allows you to test the "yes" branch in your code - to test a "no" branch, you are necessarily going to need to know how to configure PlaceOrder with a CreditCardService that declines credit.

For more on this idea, see [the doctrine of useful objects](http://docs.eventide-project.org/user-guide/useful-objects.html).

---

More generally, in TDD we normally take complicated designs that are hard to test and refactor them into a design where something really simple but hard to test collaborates with something that is complicated but easy to test.

But for that to work at all, the components need to be able to talk to each other, and if you are going to simulate that communication in a test you are necessarily going to be coupled to the "implementation detail" that is the protocol between them.

For the case where that protocol is *stable*, having tests coupled to those details isn't, of itself, a problem in practice.  There's coupling, sure, and cost of change, but if the probability of change is negligible then the expected cost of that coupling is effectively nothing.

So the trick is identifying when our tests would require coupling to an unstable implementation protocol, and figuring out how to best mitigate the risk of change.